# How do you use the "os.path.isfile ()" with a set "path" but a variable filename in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, syntax-error, os.path

I am working on a calculator program as a part of a much larger project and when I finally thought I had it finished I tested the defined "quit" command. However, it failed and after some research, I came here. What I need to know is how to make the (path) argument have a set, pre-defined path, but also have a variable for the actual file name. eg: /HDD/APPS/(insert variable here).

This is the error and the line that the error occurred on:

```
   File "../../C.py", line 19
        if ( not os.path.isfile('/HDD/APPS/'exe)):
                                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `if ( not os.path.isfile('/HDD/APPS/' + str(exe))):`

Comment: OK, Great... Now a new error popped up. I think this time I'll just post all applicable code and let you guys figure it out. Here it is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/endergreen/PyOS/SHOE/C.py", line 54, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/home/endergreen/PyOS/SHOE/C.py", line 24, in execute
    execfile ("/../../C.py")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/../../C.py'

Comment: Whoops! I figured it out. os.path.isfile() uses symbolic links, NOT relative ones, so in this case I wouldn't be able to use '../' to go up a directory.

Answer (score 5):

Concatenate two strings:

```
>>> exe = 'exefile'
>>> '/HDD/APPS/' + exe
'/HDD/APPS/exefile'
```

More preferably, use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('/HDD/APPS/', exe)
'/HDD/APPS/exefile'
```

Comment: Why is it preferable to use os.path.join in this case? If you don't, can it cause unexpected behavior?

Comment: @TechDude, os.path.join takes care of separator (/). OSes have different separators.

Comment: In that case, would it also be correct to leave out the final directory's trailing slash? Like this: `os.path.join('/HDD/APPS', exe)`

In fact, shouldn't it be preferable to leave out the final directory's trailing slash to make sure the correct separator will be used for that OS?

Comment: @TechDude, os.path.join handles trailing separator correctly.

Comment: I'll have to run some tests if I ever use an OS with a different separator; however, if I understand you correctly, on an OS that uses a colon (:) as a separator, your code `os.path.join('/HDD/APPS/', 'test.exe')` should correctly ensure the result will be 'HDD:APPS:exefile' despite the fact that slashes were used before the join. Is this correct?

Comment: @TechDude, I meant `os.path.join('HDD', 'APPS', 'test.exe')`

Comment: Ah, now this makes sense. I thought that I was somehow misunderstanding what I was reading about this elsewhere.